# Best practice to update a column that depends on itself (or on another column) in Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-core

In SQL I can write like this

```
UPDATE TestObjects SET Num = Num + 1 WHERE Id = 1;
```

This statement updates a column with a value that depends on itself. This example can easily be extended to depending on another column. I don't need to know the value of `Num`, I just ask it to increment itself regardless of its value.

If I were to do it in EF Core

```
var testObject = _context.TestObjects.Single(x => x.Id == 1);
testObject.Num++;
_context.TestObjects.Update(testObject);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

I'd have to first retrieve the record. I need to know the value of `Num` before I could increment it. Between retrieving the entity and saving it, if there's other thread already incremented the column, saving this entity would result in erroneous value. I know I can use a transaction with Isolation Level of RepeatableRead or above to lock the record upon retrieval. Is this the only way?

What's the industry's best practice for this kind of problem?

Comment: Best practice? Optimistic concurrency. Locking is evil.

Comment: @gurkan, that’s not exactly what I’m looking for. My case is specific to update only and base on other columns.

Comment: @GertArnold How is optimistic concurrency relevant in my scenario? Moreover optimistic concurrency is not feasible in highly contentious table.